# Telerik Disabling ReportViewer Toolbar Buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, telerik-reporting

I would like to disable `PrintViewToogleButton` once it is clicked for `PrintView`. I do not want to go back to interactive mode again. The main reason for this is that I generate report with images for over 300 pages and RAM extremely goes up to 2GB while using interactive view mode. But printview mode is OK.

I couldn't handle this. **Firstly I really wonder how to disable buttons programmatically**.

For this purpose, I came up with another solution. I always set the `PrintPreview` view mode to the `ReportViewer` as following:

```
private void ReportViewer_OnRenderingBegin(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (VehiclePass01ViewModel.pageRenderMode != ViewMode.PrintPreview)
    {
        this.reportViewer.ViewMode = ViewMode.PrintPreview;
    } 
}
```

But in this case, total page number changes strangely as shown on the attachments. Normally there are 343 pages. When I click on the button again, total page number changes to 685, 681, 686 or 684. But actually, page number is still 343 on the report. If I try to go to next pages by buttons, it goes until 343 despite the count is 68X.

If disabling button would exist, that could be awesome.

[image: bug]